# Android application IP configuration

Tags: android

I am working on an android application which talks to server for data. The IP address and port number is configured into the android application code . Now if my server ip changes or port changes i have to build the application again and again . Can anyone provide a solution for this problem????

Comment: You have to change and rebuild if your URL changes

Comment: Why is your ip/port changing so much?

The bottom line is that the app has to know where to go to get the data. You will either have to rebuild each time your ip changes OR have a static server that your app can check to find the current ip/port. You will then have to update that static server each time your ip/port changes instead of the app.

Comment: @ Droid i do not want to hard code URL into the android application.

Comment: if the users are going to be using the app within the same network that is a wifi sys or something, then allow them to enter the ip and the port number themselves and use that. simple. i doubt if there's any other way!

Comment: @ Dhara Shah This seems useful  or i can provide a simple user interface where user can enter ip address and port number as an input and i will fetch the data and construct my URL .

Comment: yes that way.. go ahead then

Answer (score 0):

I think this is **not the perfect** answer but what you can do is if you are going to publish your app on google play store. you can also push some data to your android device using **GCM(Google cloud messaging)**. Send the IP and port number in the GCM message to the device and accordingly use your app to communicate with that server with provided IP and port in the GCM message. **Device must have google play services installed**. 
Servers have **static ip** so your IP should not change so frequently. 
Checkout [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) here. 
You can also send some data in the GCM message. Save the data (in your case ip address and port number of your server) on local storage and read IP:port of the server from that file.